# ¿Porque no funciona overlflow: auto en el eje de la x?

Tags: html

Estaba tratando de hacer un contenedor el cual se supone que se debería desbordar su contenido en horizontal y aparecer una barra para desplazarse horizontalmente (con el uso de overlfow: auto) ya que el ancho del contenedor padre es menor que la suma del ancho de sus hijos, pero en lugar de eso, interpreto que se desborda en vertical y por eso que aparece un barra para desplazarse verticalmente. Mi pregunta es, como puedo obtener la barra horizontal y su respectivo desplazamiento en el eje de la x? (Y no en el de la y).

Éste es parte de mi código html:

```
<div style = "width: 100%; height: 18%; overflow: auto;">
        <div style = "width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: #b01e1e;">
            <div style= "float: left; width: 11.11%; height: 100%; justify-content: center; align-items: center; display: flex; vertical-align: middle;"><b><p>Cabecera1</p></b></div>
            <div style= "float: left; width: 11.11%; height: 100%; justify-content: center; align-items: center; display: flex; vertical-align: middle;"><b><p>Cabecera2</p></b></div>
            <div style= "float: left; width: 11.11%; height: 100%; justify-content: center; align-items: center; display: flex; vertical-align: middle;"><b><p>Cabecera3</p></b></div>
            <div style= "float: left; width: 11.11%; height: 100%; justify-content: center; align-items: center; display: flex; vertical-align: middle;"><b><p>Cabecera4</p></b></div>
            <div style= "float: left; width: 11.11%; height: 100%; justify-content: center; align-items: center; display: flex; vertical-align: middle;"><b><p>Cabecera5</p></b></div>
            <div style= "float: left; width: 11.11%; height: 100%; justify-content: center; align-items: center; display: flex; vertical-align: middle;"><b><p>Cabecera6</p></b></div>
            <div style= "float: left; width: 11.11%; height: 100%; justify-content: center; align-items: center; display: flex; vertical-align: middle;"><b><p>Cabecera7</p></b></div>
            <div style= "float: left; width: 11.11%; height: 100%; justify-content: center; align-items: center; display: flex; vertical-align: middle;"><b><p>Cabecera8</p></b></div>
            <div style= "float: left; width: 11.11%; height: 100%; justify-content: center; align-items: center; display: flex; vertical-align: middle;"><b><p>Cabecera9</p></b></div>
            <div style= "float: left; width: 11.11%; height: 100%; justify-content: center; align-items: center; display: flex; vertical-align: middle;"><b><p>Cabecera10</p></b></div>
            <div style= "float: left; width: 11.11%; height: 100%; justify-content: center; align-items: center; display: flex; vertical-align: middle;"><b><p>Cabecera11</p></b></div>
            <div style= "float: left; width: 11.11%; height: 100%; justify-content: center; align-items: center; display: flex; vertical-align: middle;"><b><p>Cabecera12</p></b></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

En el código que envías existen varios problemas. El principal es que debes entender que el % siempre se estaba tomando a partir del tamaño que ocupaba el contenedor. Es decir, que si el contenedor se extiende ciertos pixeles, el contenido % también lo hará en proporción. El contenido estaba superando el 100% y este era el motivo por el que caía.

Sin modificar demasiado la estructura de tu código, te propongo que pruebes la siguiente:

```
<div style="overflow-x: auto;overflow-y: hidden;">
    <div style="width: fit-content;background-color: #b01e1e;display: flex; align-items: center;">
        <div style="padding: 13px 30px;"><p><b>Cabecera1</b></p></div>
        <div style="padding: 13px 30px;"><p><b>Cabecera2</b></p></div>
        <div style="padding: 13px 30px;"><p><b>Cabecera3</b></p></div>
        <div style="padding: 13px 30px;"><p><b>Cabecera4</b></p></div>
        <div style="padding: 13px 30px;"><p><b>Cabecera5</b></p></div>
        <div style="padding: 13px 30px;"><p><b>Cabecera6</b></p></div>
        <div style="padding: 13px 30px;"><p><b>Cabecera7</b></p></div>
        <div style="padding: 13px 30px;"><p><b>Cabecera8</b></p></div>
        <div style="padding: 13px 30px;"><p><b>Cabecera9</b></p></div>
        <div style="padding: 13px 30px;"><p><b>Cabecera10</b></p></div>
        <div style="padding: 13px 30px;"><p><b>Cabecera11</b></p></div>
        <div style="padding: 13px 30px;"><p><b>Cabecera12</b></p></div>
        <div style="padding: 13px 30px;"><p><b>Cabecera13</b></p></div>
        <div style="padding: 13px 30px;"><p><b>Cabecera14</b></p></div>
        <div style="padding: 13px 30px;"><p><b>Cabecera15</b></p></div>
        <div style="padding: 13px 30px;"><p><b>Cabecera16</b></p></div>
        <div style="padding: 13px 30px;"><p><b>Cabecera17</b></p></div>
        <div style="padding: 13px 30px;"><p><b>Cabecera18</b></p></div>
        <div style="padding: 13px 30px;"><p><b>Cabecera19</b></p></div>
        <div style="padding: 13px 30px;"><p><b>Cabecera20</b></p></div>
        <div style="padding: 13px 30px;"><p><b>Cabecera21</b></p></div>     
    </div>
</div>
```

En el div principal, en lugar de utilizar "overflow: auto;" te recomiendo jugar con "overflow-x" y "overflow-y". De esta manera podrás hacer que funcione según tus necesidades independientemente del contenido de esta.

También te recomiendo retirar todos los porcentajes y dejar que el contenido fluya según sus necesidades, aunque también podrías utilizar max-width para establecer máximos.

Para finalizar, para centrar todos los contenidos verticalmente, utiliza "align-items: center;" en el div contenedor(el que tiene el display:flex). Tal y como lo habías hecho funcionaba (poniendo flex en todos los elementos), pero te estabas trayendo problemas con ello.